# Modify Stripe checkout result behavior

Tags: node.js, angular, stripe-payments

I'm trying to change the behavior of the stripe checkout result.

Currently, when the payment details pass the basic validation, it will return a token and it will change the "pay" button to a "tick".

[image]

So is it possible to change the button to other status such as failed after I submit a charge request on server code and it failed due to whatever reason?

Process flow:

Submit payment details -> get token -> submit charge from my server -> receive result from my server -> update the button status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to change this behavior as it's owned by Stripe. This button indicates that the card details are valid and that you can move to the next step which is charging the card.

Otherwise, you should build your own payment form using [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements) so that you own the layout and the user-feedback. You would be able to send the token via ajax to your server and only display an update to your customer after you've used the token successfully or not server-side.